Question about weak and pointwise convergence
I have a question about weak topology.

Definition: If $X$ is a LCS, the weak topology on $X$, denoted by "wk" or $\sigma(X,X^*)$, is the topology defined by the family of seminorms
$\{p_f : f \in X*\}$, where $p_f(x):=|f(x)| for x \in X$.

If is further mentioned:

A net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ in X converges weakly to $x_0$, iff $p_f(x_i)
> \rightarrow p_f(x_0)$.

Since $p_f(x):=|f(x)|$ for $x \in X$. This would mean that for a net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ to converge weakly to $x_0$ means that $f(x_i) \rightarrow f(x_0)$ for all $f \in X^*$.
Well, this sounds familiar. This sounds alot like pointwise convergence.
Pointwise convergence:
Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of a function $f_n:D \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$
and $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$. Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise iff $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every $x \in D$.
So my question is:
Is weak convergence in $X$, "equal" to pointwise convergence on $X^*$?
(Or more general: What is the relation between weak convergence in $X$ and pointwise convergence in $X^*$?)

If $X$ is a Banach space and $E,F$ are closed subspaces of $X,X^*$, respectively, then the members of $F$ as as functions on $E$, and the members of $E$ act as functions on $F$ via their canonical inclusion $\Phi:X\to X^{**}$ into $X^{**}$ given by $\Phi(x)(x^*)=x^*(x)$. In particular, the members of $X$ can be identified with members of $X^{**}$ and therefore act as functions on $X^*$.
In that sense, weak convergence in $X$ is the same as pointwise convergence on $X^*$. More precisely, a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ is weakly convergent to $x\in X$ iff $(\Phi(x_i))_{i\in I}$ is pointwise convergent to $\Phi(x^*)$.
In general, for closed subspaces of $E,F$ of $X,X^*$, respectively, we can define the topology $\sigma(E,F)$ on $E$ to be the one defined by the family of seminorms $\{p_f:f\in F\}$, where $p_f(x)=|f(x)|$ for $x\in E$. Then a net $(x_\lambda)\subset E$ is $\sigma(E,F)$ convergent to $x\in E$ iff $(\Phi(x_i)|_F)_{i\in I}$ is pointwise convergent to $\Phi(x)|_F$. Replacing $X,X^*$ with $X^*,X^**$, we can take $E=X^*$ and $F=\Phi(X)\subset X^{**}$, and this results in the weak$^*$-topology on $X^*$, which is pointwise convergence on $X$ (as opposed to the weak topology on $X^*$, which is pointwise convergene on $X^{**}$).

Given $x \in X$ define $F_x (f)=f(x)$ on $X^{*}.$ Then $x_i \to x$ weakly  iff $F_{x_i}$ converges pointwise to $F_x$ on $X^{*}$.
